# web setup wizard displays blank page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.1.0

I was trying to install a free theme (fashionista) using system>web setup wizard>component manager. It completed readiness check and backup steps during installation.

During the next step (new purchase status page) it started installation and showed the text

```
update application is running
```

But it took very long and showed the message 'script stopped or not responding'. It gave the option to continue or stop the script. Whatever I choose, the page (and browser) was not responding after that.So I closed the browser.

Then I rolled back the media and code using the following command

```
magento setup:rollback -c filename -m filename
```

But now when I go to system>web setup wizard, it opens a blank page(page title 'magento updater', URL- magento/update/index.php ).

How can I resolve it ? Please help.

Comment: Site setup/upgrade has log, what did you see in var/log/setup* .log or update*.log?

Comment: Also check for a file named `var/.upgrade.err.status` or something. Rename it or delete it and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the /setup blank page and finally found a fix last night. In my case i was getting a 500 error when i hit the page and in the logs I was getting the error message in my magento error log:

```
Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Warning:
SessionHandler::read()
```

Apparently Magento 2 setup will not work if you aren't using default file caching for sessions and the problem in this case is known in Magento 2 and described here [Magento 2 Docs Troubleshooting](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_session.html).

What fixed the issue was editing app/etc/env.php and replacing whatever you have for session save with

```
 'session' =>
  array (
    'save' => 'files',
  ),
```

From the docs it looks like this issue has been known for some time. It seems like a very simple condition to detect, so it's frustrating that rather than adding something to the codebase that alerts you of the problem if you try to hit /setup, a page was added to the docs.